# I specified my database name in database.php of my cakephp. However, I still cant seem to insert data in any table of my database

Tags: database, cakephp, insertion

I am just a newbie in cakephp and struggled a lot as a beginner, I hope im not exaggerating. I believe I was on the right track of coding a simple registration application when I found out that I am not able to insert any data in my database. The name of my database is "cake" and this is the default configuration:

```
public $default = array{
    'datasource'=>'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent'=>false,
    'host'=>'localhost',
    'login'=>'root',
    'password'=>'',
    'database'=>'cake',
    'schema'=>'',
    'prefix'=>''
}
```

By the way, the index page of my localhost says that I am connected to the database.

Comment: the main question is: how are you inserting data into the database then? we would need to see some actual code.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for the response. This is what I have in my controller:

<?php
class UsersController extends AppController
{

function register()
{
if (!empty($this->params['form']))
{
if ($this->User->save($this->params['form']))
{
$this->flash('Your registration information was accepted.',
'/users/register');
} else {
$this->flash('There was a problem with your registration',
'/users/register');
}
}
}
}
?>

Comment: Am I doing it right? it doesn't display anything though i told it to do so.  :( it's really frustrating.

Comment: no you are not :) you should read the documentation and the tutorials on how to correctly work with forms in 2.0 - no need to use params[form] ever in cases where you use the Form helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try these

- Your DB config tells me that you are using cakephp 2 +, use

`$this->User->save($this->request->data);`

- Set your debug level higher than 0 in Config/core.php to see errors if they exist
- Generally the save doesn't work because of validation. You can list invalid fields  by

`debug($this->User->invalidFields()); // will only show when debug > 0`

- The sql log in the bottom (only when debug > 0) will show the insert query, try pasting that query directly into mysql from your mysql front end. See if there are any errors over types, constraints.

Comment: hi Kishor! Thank you for the response. I followed your instructions. I was also able to find out that it does not enter either of the if-else statement. But it do acquires data from the form.

Comment: you mentioned that i am using cakephp 2, would there be any difference with the previous versions?

Comment: i think i am not saving in the table.

Comment: up until now i can't seem to find the problem.  :( please help

Comment: i have read that beforesave() helps. But i dont necessarily understand it.

Comment: WHEW..KNOW WHAT..SOMETIME I REALLY THOUGHT THAT I AM THE MOST UNINTELLIGENT PERSON IN THE WORLD...this should've been resolved an hour ago. Thanks Kishor. I got two data request, I only modified one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CharmaineKhaySorila : yes previous versions of cake differ a lot. beforeSave() is callback that gets executed just before Model data is saved. glad i helped... is it solved now ? you can post what you did to solve the problem and select that as a right answer..

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seems to have mentioned this, but if your database config code is really what you posted, you should be getting a syntax error. I mean, this:

```
public $default = array{
    // ...
}
```

should be like this:

```
public $default = array(
    // ...
);
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake.. it was a typo error.. >.<  thanks bfavaretto  :)

Answer (score 0):

part of my code was actually something like this:

```
  <?php class UsersController extends AppController { 
  function register() { 
      if (!empty($this->params['form'])) { 
        if ($this->User->save($this->params['form'])) { 
          $this->flash('Your registration information was accepted.', '/users/register');
      }

      else { 
          $this->flash('There was a problem with your registration', '/users/register'); } } } } ?>
```

What i did is I changed all the "$this->params['form']" to "$this->request->data". Worked like magic. :)